# Hyperledger Fabric: tool/method that I can use in order to get a complete raw/JSON visualization of all types of transactions in HLF?

Tags: json, transactions, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I want to see complete Transaction Payloads in raw format for the following types of transactions:-

1. **Transaction Proposal**: a client sends this proposal to endorsing peer nodes.
2. **Endorsements**: endorsing peer nodes return with their own ID and signature.
3. **Proposal Response**: the result after endorsing peer nodes execute the requested chaincode, in the format of RWSet.

I have already used **Hyperledger Explorer** but it isn't showing the complete information of the transactions, it doesn't serve my purpose as:-

1. I'm more interested in **JSON** format containing **complete information** of the transaction payload.
2. It is showing **ENDORSER_TRANSACTION** and **CONFIG** types of transactions only.

Is there any other **tool/method** that I can use in order to get a complete **raw/JSON** visualization of all types of transactions in HLF?

Any relevant source/article/document will also be helpful.

***Note:** I am using test-network, the Intent is only to understand the flow.*

Answer (score 1):

The messages passed between clients and nodes are all protobuf format, not JSON. If it is sufficient to see the committed transactions (i.e. ones recorded to the ledger), you could write a block listener to capture them:

- Node.js: https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/module-fabric-network.Network.html#addBlockListener
- Java: https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway-java/release-2.2/org/hyperledger/fabric/gateway/Network.html#addBlockListener(java.util.function.Consumer)

The block events contain all the transactions recorded to the ledger. You can extract transaction read/write sets from the block events.

Transactions that are evaluated rather than submitted (so just proposals are sent to peers but are never send on to the orderer to be committed) are not recorded on the ledger so will not appear in block events.

If you really want to capture everything that goes across the wire, perhaps the easiest approach might be to use a proxy with gRPC passthrough or other traffic sniffing technique to capture the information you want at the network level. It's possible that some gRPC logging might allow you to record all the gRPC messages but you would have to consult the gRPC implementation used by your client implementation to see if that is the case. Another option, since the code is all open source, is to modify the client implementation you are using to log the protobuf message sent and received with gRPC. Just be aware that the marshalled protobufs are a binary format so not directly human readable.

Comment: I had some success intercepting gRPC messages between the peer and chaincode using [grpc-dump](https://github.com/bradleyjkemp/grpc-tools), which I think should work for capturing fabric client messages. There are some notes on the [fabric-proxy](https://github.com/hyperledgendary/fabric-proxy) if you want to give something similar a try.

Answer (score 0):

[Hyperledger Blockchain Explorer](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer) is the best solution. Although it does not respond as you want it to. But it has all the data and the appropriate interface framework available. Edit some code, convert its data and you will have the tools you want.